# std::to_string return empty string when using std::allocator

Tags: c++, string

I got the empty return of std::to_string when I use std::allocator. The code is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::allocator<std::string> allocatorStr;
    auto const pStr = allocatorStr.allocate(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { *(pStr + i) = std::to_string(i); }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { std::cout << *(pStr + i) << std::endl; }

    return 0;
}
```

But if I change the line `*(pStr + i) = std::to_string(i);`to `*(pStr + i) = "string";` I could get non-empty output.
I don't know where is wrong. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate), (emphasis mine):

> [`allocate`] ... allocates `n * sizeof(T)` bytes of **uninitialized** storage

In other words, there are no valid `std::string` objects there yet and trying to use them (even as the target of a copy) invokes undefined behaviour (I got a segfault).

To fix this, use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) to construct the needed `std::string` objects immediately after calling `allocate`:

```
auto pStr = allocatorStr.allocate(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { new (pStr + i) std::string; }
...
```

Then, [it works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0URRU4VdTZzo3wlX)

---

**Edit:** Responding to @user17732522's comment below (which makes a lot of sense), there are advantages to using [`std::allocator_traits::construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct) instead of `placement new`; the comment explains what they are.  This does essentially the same job as `placement new`, but in a more flexible way (from the allocator's perspective).  And since one is doing that, one might as well also use [`std::allocator_traits::allocate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/allocate), since this has a few advantages too.

The code then becomes:

```
using MyAllocatorTraits = std::allocator_traits <decltype (allocatorStr)>;
auto pStr = MyAllocatorTraits::allocate (allocatorStr, 5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { MyAllocatorTraits::construct (allocatorStr, pStr + i); }
...
```

[Updated live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eAvptzImqaFA0WoP)

Comment: I love how much of a disaster C++ is. "Strongly-typed" -> here is a T pointer to not-a-T, enjoy!

Comment: @GManNickG To be fair, if `allocate` returned a `void*` then it would be harder to find the address of the n'th object-to-be. On another hand, perhaps it would have been better if placement-new had special syntax for providing that index instead. C++ is strongly typed only in "typical" use cases. Once you get into fancy stuff such as separating allocation from initialisation, you delve into the weak typing.

Comment: @GManNickG • Yep, C++ is not a nanny language.  It gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot, and still have enough left over for the rigging of a schooner.

Comment: You might want to construct the object with `std::allocator_traits::construct`, which will allow an allocator-specific `.construct` to be called (if `std::allocator` is replaced with a different one) and will also work in a constant expression since C++20.

Comment: @user17732522 OK, thanks, answer edited.  Hope I got it right - new territory for me (although I did vaguely know about this, but not when I posted that answer).

Comment: @PaulSanders Looks good to me.